# Microsoft Ace Driver missing numbers

Tags: c#

I am using the Microsoft Ace Driver to read text file, sometimes it put null in the place of big numbers, to reproduce this bug, I have done the next steps:

I have created a text file with those value:

```
columnA;ColumnB
0;AAA
0;AAA
0;AAA
(0;AAA is repeated around 50 rows)
69000000000;BBB
```

The result: I get all the 0 and AAA, and on the last row, I get null and BBB.

The interesting thing, is that if I create this file:

```
columnA;ColumnB
0;AAA
0;AAA
69000000000;BBB
```

The ace driver return the long number.

Any idea why the ace driver delete long numbers in "big" files?

Comment: Can you post the connection string you are using please? There are a number of Extended Properties you can set which can effect the driver behaviour. See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/ for example.

Comment: Hi, I am using a basic connection string and I have a Schema.ini file next to the file with Format=Delimited(;) and ColNameHeader=True .